# Interactive field mapping tool in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, lexer, data-mapping

I want to build a field mapping tool in `JavaScript` where in users can perform mapping of source object to destination object based on defined business rules.

Refer to the following image for the reference wherein there is one `Opportunity` source object and `Transaction` destination object involved. Now, to perform field mapping user has to perform following steps

[image]

1. choose field from the source object `Opportunity`
2. choose the relational operators, it could be CONTAINS,NOT EQUAL, EQUALS
3. mentioned the value
4. choose field from destination object `Transaction`
5. mentioned value to be updated
6. user can add logical operators like ( AND and OR ) to combine the conditions

In order to develop such tool , I am looking for some definite road-map if anyone can suggest. So far, what I have explored is this can be achieved through lexer or parser but not sure how and which parser do i need to use in javascript. If anyone had developed such tool before then please share the road-map at least so that I can hunt more in that direction.